# Rename macos subfolders in my home directory to lowercase

Tags: macos, mac, rename, home-folder

I'm looking to change the casing of macOS's default folders (the ones that sit in my home folder) to lowercase.

```
~/myname/Desktop -> ~/myname/desktop
~/myname/Downloads -> ~/myname/downloads
~/myname/Music -> ~/myname/music
```

If possible, it'd be great to avoid moving the home folder itself, and play with symlinks.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: `sudo mv ~/Downloads ~/downloads` from terminal worked for me.  I'm running Lion with default HFS+ settings (case preserving not case sensitive) - if you are on later version or different filesystem and it doesn't work edit results of `diskutil info /` into your question.

Comment: @lx07 This seemed to work! Do you think it'll be dangerous to rename `~/Library`, too?

Comment: No it will be fine - as long as you don't have case sensitive file system.  I tried it to rename to `~/library` and it caused no issue.

Comment: Thank you! It worked well, no problems so far :)